# HTML template on business class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, razor

I want to generate a pdf file report with some values from my db. I am using ASPPDF library. This library has a method called ImportFromUrl which can receive an html markup and return a pdf file. I am using MVC so I have implemented a controller method which does the following:

1. Calls a business class which gets the values from the db and stores them into a DTO object.
2. Once the DTO is back in my controller, I call a ViewRenderer class. This class searches for a Razor template and plugs DTO object as its model. The class will return the html generated as a string inside my controller.
3. Use the AspPdf function to convert html into a pdf file.
4. Insert the pdf file back into the database with the help of the business class.

This is working totally fine. However, due to the project requirements I need this method not to be exposed as an action in a controller, but rather be consumed directly from the business class. The issue is that, in order to generate the html code I am using a razor template and I will not be able to use it. My idea was to have an html template inside the business class that resembles the razor template and generate the html string directly from the business class.
Is there a way I can do this?
Greetings
Luis.

Comment: Sounds like you want Html.Action instead of Html.RenderAction: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/

Comment: Not really. This will be still an action on my controller. I want to move all this logic to my business class but still be able to fill in an html like template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ChildActionOnly` attribute to make sure your action doesn't get called from the browser.

[ChildActionOnlyAttribute from the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute.aspx):

> Represents an attribute that is used to indicate that an action method should be called only as a child action.

Comment: Not really. This will be still an action on my controller. I want to move all this logic to my business class but still be able to fill in an html like template.

Comment: You're right, it will still be an action on your controller, but it won't be exposed as your project requirements specify.